# retina display image dimentions

Tags: css, retina-display

I have created icons of 2 sized *40px X 40px* and *80px X 80px* for normal display and retina display respectively.

what is the proper way to use these 2 sizes of icons?

I mean should i change the dimensions of element for retina version to 80px X 80px or use background-size property to fit the large icons in 40px X 40px size?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the Safari Web Content Guide from Apple.

[Specifying a Webpage icon](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html)

Comment: My question is not about apple-touch-icon, it's about general image icons used in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are using these 'icons'.  Are they web app icons, images within the web page or background images?

Firstly retina images should be named with @x2.e.g.

**Standard**

> sample.png

**Retina**

> sample@x2.png

For web app icons see the previous answer from cpattersonv1

**Background Images**

This can be achieved with the use of media queries.  A media query to target retina capable devices would look like this.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
}
```

From within the media query you can then specify your retina image for the background-image.

Comment: using @x2 is not mandatory, we can use any image name like sample_ratina.png

Comment: Your answer did not address my query, do i need to change the size of icon in css or html to work it properly in ratina display?

Answer (score 0):

I found that i need to keep the dimensions in CSS same for both normal and ratina versions, and fit the large image in normal dimension using `background-size` property.